# HTTPListener and servlet

Tags: servlets, httplistener

We have an servlet which sends messages to a queue.
It gets the message from a request object it got from Paypal. 
The servlet is called IPNServlet.

Note that this is a standalone servlet which is not a part of any MDB.

For some reason the following mapping in my web.xml does not work  (requests to this servlet bundled in the WAR file on JBoss EAP 5.1 are not handled)

```
<servlet-name>IPNServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.temenos.paypal.servlet.IPNServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

<servlet-mapping>IPNServlet</servlet-mapping>
<url-pattern>/IPNServlet</url-pattern>
```

By the way of this web.xml, shouldnt a request made to https:// HOSTNM:8443/IPNServlet be processed as expected ?
Where HOSTNM is the name of the IP.

Is there a separate HTTP Listener that is needed ?

Comment: https and 8080 is not normal. Check your configuration once

Comment: its deployed to 8443. Is a separate httplistener always needed ina ddition to a httpservlet ?

Comment: What is HttpListener? You mean session listeners, request listeners and servlet context listeners. These are not needed.